# Linked variables in optimization problem using pyomo piecewise

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo, piecewise, coin-or-cbc

I am struggling with "linked" variables in a cost optimization problem. Overall I have four  variables: `varX1`, `varX2`, `varY1` and `varY2` which are paired in the following manner:

```
if 0 <= varX1 < 1 then varY1 = 0
if 1 <= varX1 <= 6 then varY1 = 1
```

and

```
if 0 <= varX2 < 1 then varY2 = 0 
if 1 <= varX2 <= 5 then varY2 = 1
```

I have tried to model the relationship of `varX1` and varY1`as well as`varX2`and`varY2` using pyomos piecewise trying to recreate the example from https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/main/examples/pyomo/piecewise/step.py.

Full model code is:

```
import pyomo.environ as po

costsX1 = 4
costsX2 = 6

costsY1 = 2
costsY2 = 1

a1 = 4
a2 = 3

model = po.ConcreteModel()

model.VarX1 = po.Var(bounds=(0,6))
model.VarX2 = po.Var(bounds=(0,5))

model.VarY1 = po.Var(within=po.Binary)
model.VarY2 = po.Var(within=po.Binary)

model.cons1 = po.Constraint(expr=model.VarX1+model.VarX2==5)
model.cons2 = po.Constraint(expr=a1*model.VarY1+ a2*model.VarY2>=3)

model.obj = po.Objective(expr=costsX1*model.VarX1+costsY1*a1*model.VarY1+costsX2*model.VarX2+costsY2*a2*model.VarY2,
                         sense=po.minimize)

DOMAIN_PTS_X1 = [0, 1, 1, 6]
RANGE_PTS_Y1  = [0, 0, 1, 1]

DOMAIN_PTS_X2 = [0, 1, 1, 5]
RANGE_PTS_Y2  = [0, 0, 1, 1]

model.piece1 = po.Piecewise(model.VarX1, model.VarY1,
                            pw_pts=DOMAIN_PTS_X1,
                            pw_constr_type='LB',
                            f_rule=RANGE_PTS_Y1,
                            pw_repn='INC')

model.piece2 = po.Piecewise(model.VarX2, model.VarY2,
                            pw_pts=DOMAIN_PTS_X2,
                            pw_constr_type='LB',
                            f_rule=RANGE_PTS_Y2,
                            pw_repn='INC')

opt = po.SolverFactory('cbc')
result_obj = opt.solve(model, tee=True)

model.pprint()
```

I get the following result

```
4 Var Declarations
    VarX1 : Size=1, Index=None
        Key  : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
        None :     0 :   5.0 :     6 : False : False :  Reals
    VarX2 : Size=1, Index=None
        Key  : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
        None :     0 :   0.0 :     5 : False : False :  Reals
    VarY1 : Size=1, Index=None
        Key  : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
        None :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
    VarY2 : Size=1, Index=None
        Key  : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
        None :     0 :   1.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
```

As one can see, there is no pairing of `varX1` and `varY1`.

Can anyone help me with that?

---

### Solution:

With the help of AirSquid I was able to find a simple solution for my problem. I gave up on using pyomos piecewise function and introduced additional constraints to the model. The following model works as desired

```
import pyomo.environ as po

costsX1 = 4
costsX2 = 6

costsY1 = 2
costsY2 = 1

a1 = 4
a2 = 3

model = po.ConcreteModel()

model.VarX1 = po.Var(bounds=(0,6))
model.VarX2 = po.Var(bounds=(0,5))

model.VarY1 = po.Var(within=po.Binary)
model.VarY2 = po.Var(within=po.Binary)

model.cons1 = po.Constraint(expr=model.VarX1+model.VarX2==5)
model.cons2 = po.Constraint(expr=a1*model.VarY1+ a2*model.VarY2>=3)

model.con3 = po.Constraint(expr=model.VarY1 <= model.VarX1)
model.con4 = po.Constraint(expr=model.VarY1 >= model.VarX1/6)

model.con5 = po.Constraint(expr=model.VarY2 <= model.VarX2)
model.con6 = po.Constraint(expr=model.VarY2 >= model.VarX2/5)

model.obj = po.Objective(expr=costsX1*model.VarX1+costsY1*a1*model.VarY1+costsX2*model.VarX2+costsY2*a2*model.VarY2,
                         sense=po.minimize)

opt = po.SolverFactory('cbc')
result_obj = opt.solve(model, tee=True)

model.pprint()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about this differently.  Consider `y` to be an "indicator" variable.  In this case it *indicates* which range x is in, or more precisely, it *indicates* the upper and lower bounds on x.  So, now the task is to do a little algebra with binary numbers to make that work...

Let's think about the low....

```
x >= 1 * y
```

Works for both values of `y in {0, 1}`

And the high ...  if y=0 we want 1, if y=1, we want 6...  A little algebra:

```
x <= 1 + 5 * y
```

Comment: Hi! Your proposal got me to the correct solution. Now that I look at it, it is kind of embarrassing that I was not able to come up with such an easy solution myself. Nevertheless, thank you so much for your comment!